# Botão sair com mensagem

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando usar o `bootstrap 3` junto com o `VRaptor 3` e estou com um problema no menu.

Acontece que tenho nesse menu a opção "sair" e estou perdida.

Preciso que quando o usuário clicar no "sair", abra uma janela perguntando se é isso mesmo que deseja e dando "ok" sair do sistema.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rede Olp</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="<c:url value="/inicial"/>">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<c:url value="/logout"/>">Sair</a></li>

                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode incluir uma modal para informar o seu usuario se deseja realmente sair.

### Exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rede Olp</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="<c:url value=" /inicial "/>">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sair</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Atenção</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Deseja sair do Sistema ?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<c:url value=" /logout "/>">Sim</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja tambem no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/o2gkvy9e/show/)

Comment: ficou do jeito que eu queria. Só mais uma dúvida. Ao clicar no botão "SIM" eu tenho que sair do Sistema. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sim</button>` , como eu coloco a url que após ser clicado deve sair do sistema?  E tenho que colocar isso no botão... : `<c:url value="/logout"/>`

Comment: @MarciaPereiraReis voce pode incluir a tag a e apenas colocar as classes btn btn-primary para o comportamento ficar igual ao do seu sair, editei a resposta com este detalhe.

Comment: Desse jeito?: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" <c:url value="/logout"/> >Sim</button>` ... nossa, to perdidinha nisso.

Comment: Assim  `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<c:url value=" /logout "/>">Sim</a>`

Comment: Coloquei desse jeito `<button type="button"> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<c:url value="/logout"/>">Sim</a></button>` funcionou, apenas o botão ficou feio demais. Vou ver como posso resolver isso. Pelo menos avançou bastante rsrsrsr obrigada

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`confirm()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) para obter a confirmação do usuário, se ele realmente quer sair.

Como o elemento é um *hyperlink* que já aponta para o recurso que realiza o *logout*, você precisa somente prevenir ([**`Event#preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault)) que ele seja chamado caso o retorno do `confirm` seja falso.

Se o usuário pressionar <kbd>OK</kbd> o comportamento padrão do navegador continuará e o recurso será chamado, do contrário nenhuma ação será tomada:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#sair').on('click', function(event){
    
    if (!confirm('Pressione "OK" se deseja realmente sair.'))
        event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id='sair' href='/logout/'>Sair</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado @renan , mas usando o modal ficou mais elegante. A sua dica funcionou. Porém, vou usar a dica do Gabriel ... estou tentando fazer o botão do modal realmente sair do sistema. rsssrr

Comment: Na próxima você **detalha** que é para usar modal.

Comment: obrigada mais uma vez pela gentileza em me ajudar. Detalharei na próxima. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Segue a solução:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/logout"/>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Sim</a>
```

Muito obrigada a todos que me ajudaram!